# remove the first row for each group

Tags: r

suppose I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,2),rep(4,3),rep(5, 2)), score = c(30, 10, 22, 44, 6, 5, 20, 35, 2, 60, 14,5)) 

   group score
1      1    30
2      1    10
3      1    22
4      2    44
5      2     6
6      3     5
7      3    20
8      4    35
9      4     2
10     4    60
11     5    14
12     5     5
```

I want to remove the first row for each group, the expected out put should look like this:

```
   group score
1      1    10
2      1    22
3      2     6
4      3    20
5      4     2
6      4    60
7      5     5
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An option with `dplyr` is to select rows ignoring 1st row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(2:n())

#  group score
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1.00 10.0 
#2  1.00 22.0 
#3  2.00  6.00
#4  3.00 20.0 
#5  4.00  2.00
#6  4.00 60.0 
#7  5.00  5.00
```

---

Another way is shown by @Rich Scriven in now deleted answer

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(-1)
```

Comment: Note that if a group only has 1 row, then `slice(-1)` will keep that row. `df[duplicated(df$group),]` (by @a-webb) will have such row removed.

Comment: From my test, slice(-1) will remove the row if a group only has 1 row, whereas slice(2:n()) will keep it.

Answer (score 9):

Quite simple with `duplicated`

```
df[duplicated(df$group),]
```

```
   group score
2      1    10
3      1    22
5      2     6
7      3    20
9      4     2
10     4    60
12     5     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` option would be to check the adjacent elements

```
df[c(FALSE,df$group[-1]==df$group[-nrow(df)]),]
#   group score
#2      1    10
#3      1    22
#5      2     6
#7      3    20
#9      4     2
#10     4    60
#12     5     5
```

Here I removed the first observation in 'group' (`df$group[-1]`) and compared (`==`) with the vector in which last observation is removed (`df$group[-nrow(df)])`).  As the `length` of the comparison is one less than the `nrow` of the dataset, we pad with `FALSE` at the top and use this as logical index to subset the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::filter(df, group == lag(group))
   group score
1     1    10
2     1    22
3     2     6
4     3    20
5     4     2
6     4    60
7     5     5
```

See `lead` and `lag` of package `dplyr` for more information:

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html